# Computation with big values in JavaCard

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to develop an applet in JavaCard which will have to compute operations with big values (500bits approximately).
In more detail, I need to do an addition and a multiplication.

As I am using JavaCard 2.2.2, my big values can only be represented by an **array of bytes** or an **array of shorts**.

My question is the following : if I define how to do a multiplication and an addition of two arrays like described above, could I develop an applet to do what I want ?

Thank you very much to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use javacards [BigNumber](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/framework/math/BigNumber.html) to calculate the operations and then store with the toBytes function.